# RPI: How to write python script output to log file with autostart

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

How can I log the output from a python script to a file when the script starts automatically at boot?

I have a python program with a tKinter (so an interactive GUI)
Therefore I have made a file in the /etc/xdg/autostart folder with the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual_assistant
Exec=sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/va.py &>> /home/pi/logs/va.txt
```

However, the log file never gets created.
Any suggestions to solve this? Or should I do it in a different way?
Note: I'm sure about the paths - tested this by running the python script via CLI

Many thanks for any help

Comment: [Wrap](https://askubuntu.com/a/873801/877) your `Exec` line in `bash -c`.

Comment: hm, no luck. 
I created a file launcher.sh with
sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/va.py &> /home/pi/logs.va_log.txt
Then I changed the autostart file to:
Exec=sudo /home/pi/Documents/launcher.sh
Program starts, but nothing logged to the file. (file gets created)

Comment: How are you creating output in your Python script? Do you have `print` statements in it? Can you add statements that display in your TKinter window what file descriptors are open? I wonder if stdout/stderr are closed or redirected in the Python code or modules. Try adding a shell `echo` in your shell wrapper to append to the log file and see if that works. Finding which things work and don't work will help narrow down the problem. The fact that the log file gets created is a clue (and a good sign).

Comment: Yes I have print statements in my python script. What I want to catch is if for any reason the python script would fail and trow an error so that I can debug. How would you add an echo in the wrapper script? Sorry for asking but I'm a bit of a geek when it comes to unix bash scripting. Could you give an example?

Comment: In your `launcher.sh` file you have a line that says `sudo python3 /home/pi/Documents/va.py &> /home/pi/logs.va_log.txt` - add a line before that one that says something like `echo 'I am here' > /home/pi/logs_test.txt` and see if that text is in that log file after you launch the script from your desktop. If that file gets text and the `logs.va_log.txt` file doesn't get anything then that tells us something is wrong in your python script (rather than the autostart/launcher stuff) and would lead to trying the file descriptor suggestion in my previous message.